# Detecting set of planes in python

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds, ransac

According that post [Detecting set of planes from point cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731442/detecting-set-of-planes-from-point-cloud)
I'm doing the same, but I don't know how to proceed with the algorithm in python. 
Would someone point a pseudo code for the algorithm in python ?
Or using any helper library like scipy ?

**I'm trying to detect two planes (two walls with an edge) and I need their normals**

The algorithm that is mentioned:

```
Pick 3 points at random.
Make a plane.
Check if each other point lies on the plane.
If enough are on the plane - recalculate a best plane from all these points and remove them from the set
If not try another 3 points
Stop when you have enough planes, or too few points left.
```

Comment: clustering? https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68

Comment: @G.B. Good idea, so I cluster the points into 2 clusers, then fit the plane for each cluster? can you write an answer with detailed approach ?

Comment: you need to first parameterize (in finite space) and then do a sweep, followed by some sort of clustering technique. For example [hough transformation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228754371_The_3D_Hough_Transform_for_plane_detection_in_point_clouds_A_review_and_a_new_accumulator_design).

Comment: What do you mean if someone has a **pseudo code**? You literally posted a pseudo code for your problem, why don't you try and implement it?
BTW, the algorithm you are looking for is called [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).